# Codec information application

Tags: codec

I need to get video/codec information from several files (avi, matroska etc).
Is there any alternative to GSpot? 
GSpot is outdated with lack of support for mkv, ogm, 264 ...

I already know [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) (really good - doesnt go as deep as GSpot) and [AviCodec](http://avicodec.duby.info/).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [VideoSpec](http://videospec.free.fr/english/) occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using always ffprobe from FFmpeg.